How to load yaml files manually and merge them by spring profile?
In a spring boot 3 application, I need to load some yaml file and merge them according to some spring profile.
Ie: I want to do the same thing as spring do with the application.yml file but with other files.
The file could not be application.yml file and will be stored in a custom folder.
Example:
First file, my-custom-folder/my-custom-file.yaml
prop1: default-value-1
prop2: default-value-2

Second file, my-custom-folder/my-custom-file-profile1.yaml
prop2: profile1-value-2

Should be load as:
prop1: default-value-1
prop2: profile1-value-2

So far, I know how to find all resources on the classpath matching my requirements:
public final class ResourceLoaderUtil {

    private static final String EMPTY_PROFILE = "";

    record ProfiledResource(Resource resource, String profile) {}

    private ResourceLoaderUtil() {
    }

    public static List<Resource> getResources(String prefix, String extension, String[] activeProfiles) throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver loader = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        String extensionWithDot = extension.startsWith(".") ? extension : "." + extension;
        Resource[] resources = loader.getResources("classpath*:" + prefix + "*" + extensionWithDot);

        List<String> activeProfilesList = new ArrayList<>();
        activeProfilesList.add(EMPTY_PROFILE);
        activeProfilesList.addAll(List.of(activeProfiles));

        return Stream.of(resources)
            .map(resource -> new ProfiledResource(resource, extractProfile(resource.getFilename())))
            .filter(profiledResource -> activeProfilesList.contains(profiledResource.profile))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(pr -> activeProfilesList.indexOf(pr.profile)))
            .map(ProfiledResource::resource)
            .toList();
    }

    private static String filenameWithoutExtension(String filename) {
        return filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
    }

    private static String extractProfile(String filename) {
        String filenameWithoutExtension = filenameWithoutExtension(filename);
        String[] split = filenameWithoutExtension.split("-", -1);
        return split.length > 1 ? split[split.length - 1] : EMPTY_PROFILE;
    }
}

        List<Resource> resources = ResourceLoaderUtil.getResources("my-custom-folder/my-custom-file", ".yml", environment.getActiveProfiles());

        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
            PropertySource<?> propertySources = loader.load("some-name", resource).getFirst();

            // how to merge propertySources ?
        }

How can I merge the PropertySource objects?
Is there a better way to load all yaml files and override the properties according to the current spring active profiles?

Your question asks about "load yaml files manually" but then you ask

Is there a better way to load all yaml files and override the properties according to the current spring active profiles?

Yes! you can get what you want without any coding if:

you can place the resource files in the normal place.

that place is src/main/resources/


adhere to a naming convention

name the two files application-my-custom-file.yaml and application-my-custom-file-profile1.yaml


specify the active profiles in a particular order (like CSS you put the one you want to "win" later).

-Dspring.profiles.active=my-custom-file,my-custom-file-profile1



Then you can inject the values into your code using
public SomeClass(@Value("${prop1}") String prop1, @Value("${prop2}") String prop2) {...


Sure this work, but it's not my need. I really need to load some custom file in a custom folder. And yes I want to reproduce what is done by spring natively with the application.yml file
